# TypeError: resize_images() got an unexpected keyword argument 'preserve_aspect_ratio'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I want to use my custom trained model on Unity. I trained a model using Tensorflow v1.13.1 and I changed .pb to bytes but I couldn't use my model. I guess Unity working Tensorflow 1.7.1. Whatever I  was trying to train a model with Tensorflow 1.7.1 but I got this message.

```
TypeError: resize_images() got an unexpected keyword argument 'preserve_aspect_ratio'
```

After this error message, I just removed preserve_aspect_ratio variable but it didn't work for me. I got this error message.

```
(tensorflow1) C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py:126: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py:266: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
WARNING:tensorflow:num_readers has been reduced to 1 to match input file shards.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 250, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py", line 291, in train
    clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, model_fn, [input_queue])
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\slim\deployment\model_deploy.py", line 193, in create_clones
    outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py", line 204, in _create_losses
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(images, true_image_shapes)
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\meta_architectures\faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py", line 688, in predict
    self._anchors.get(), image_shape, true_image_shapes))
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\meta_architectures\faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py", line 775, in _predict_second_stage
    anchors, image_shape_2d, true_image_shapes)
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\meta_architectures\faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py", line 1295, in _postprocess_rpn
    clip_window=clip_window)
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\core\post_processing.py", line 478, in batch_multiclass_non_max_suppression
    parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\utils\shape_utils.py", line 228, in static_or_dynamic_map_fn
    return tf.map_fn(fn, elems, dtype, parallel_iterations, back_prop)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\functional_ops.py", line 413, in map_fn
    swap_memory=swap_memory)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 3202, in while_loop
    result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2940, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py", line 2877, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\functional_ops.py", line 403, in compute
    packed_fn_values = fn(packed_values)
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\core\post_processing.py", line 452, in _single_image_nms_fn
    additional_fields=per_image_additional_fields)
  File "C:\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\core\post_processing.py", line 170, in multiclass_non_max_suppression
    score_threshold=score_thresh)
TypeError: non_max_suppression() got an unexpected keyword argument 'score_threshold'
```

What should I do?

Comment: The object detection API does not support tensorflow v1.7 so you will have to use v1.13 or v1.12. Also make sure your API version is the latest.

Comment: If I train with Tensorflow 1.13 or 1.12, I can't use on Unity. That is the main problem for me. Actually, I have an idea. If I can find to Tensorflow models documents old version, I can train with Tensorflow 1.7.1. What do you think about this? Is this possible?

Comment: The object detection api has a release version based on tf1.5, maybe you can try this version. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/r1.5/research/object_detection

Comment: It's not worked for me. Do you have another idea for Unity Image Classification?

Comment: Tensorflow object detection api is used for detection but not classification. Are u referring to classification or detection?

Comment: Classification or detection doesn't matter for me. Just I want to train my model and then I will import my Unity project.